# Form not generating/form is_valid = 0 for radio input forms

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am writing a survey made with radio inputs. In CMD every click on the radio inputs would result on request = POST, however the form.is_valid is false since not all required buttons are pressed. I have changed it now nothing works, it won't even request now.

Below is my code:

forms.py

```
    class introForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Intro
        fields = ['name','education','sex',]
```

models.py

```
class Intro(models.Model):
EDUCATION_CHOICES = (
                    ('1','1'),
                    ('2','2'),
                    ('3','3'),
                    ('4','4'),
                    ('G','Graduate'),
                    ('P','Professor')
                    )
SEX_CHOICES = (
           ('M','Male'),
           ('F','Female'),
           )
name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
education = models.CharField(max_length = 1,choices = EDUCATION_CHOICES)
sex = models.CharField( max_length = 1, choices = SEX_CHOICES)
```

views.py

```
def get_User_Info(request):
#form_class = introForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form_class.is_valid():           
        name = request.POST['name']
        print(name)
        sex = request.POST['sex'] 
        education = request.POST['education']           
        intro.objects.create(
            name = name,
            sex = sex,
            education = education
        )
        intro.save()
        print (connection.queries)

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/vote/") #Save data and redirect
else:
    form = introForm()
return render(request, 'Intro.html', {'introForm': form})
```

Intro.html # Wrote hastily since form can't render itself for some reason...

```
<!-- Survey/templates/Intro.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %}

<html> 
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id = "introForm">
<p><label for="name">Name:</label>
<input id=name type="text" name="subject" maxlength="15" required /></p>
<p><label for="sex">Sex:</label>
 <input type="radio" name="Sex" value="M" required>Male
<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="F" required>Female</p>


<p><label for="education">Education:</label>
 <input type="radio" name="Education" value="1" required>1
<input type="radio" name="Education" value="2" required>2
<input type="radio" name="Education" value="3" required>3
<input type="radio" name="Education" value="4" required>4
<input type="radio" name="Education" value="G" required>Graduate
<input type="radio" name="Education" value="P" required>Professor</p>
</form> 
<input type="submit" value="Next" id = "next"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form_class = introForm(request.POST)
```

You have named this variable form_class instead of form. You should be naming it the same as the form in the else statement so that you can achieve the functionality you want. Also, it should be the first line inside the if statement like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = introForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
```

Are you using the form tag in the template like so...

```
{{ introForm }}
```

Comment: Is your form definitely posting to that view? Check the form action attribute and make sure its pointing to the url for that view

Comment: Yes it is... I just double checked. CMD only shows get /thewebpage/ and then no matter what I click it doesn't update... Edit: I added the forms.py